# eCommerce - Multiple Bank Accounts Automated Transactions

Tags: e-commerce, payment

Evening

I have a client who is asking to build an eCommerce tool in which multiple stores are able to create accounts and their products in order to sell them via a web app.

This is not like any regular eCommerce sites since we are working with multiple stores each one of them with an unique bank account.

The quick solution is to ask the stores users to give me the bank account and all extra sensitive information and do the transaction via coding my self... but i don't want to mess with such delicate data that is why im looking for some service that helps me do that.

I know that i can use auth net to build something like that but my main client will have to pay for each of those merchant accounts, which is not a very good option.

Any of you had the chance to work in something like this before? Can you tell me which services you used? Would be extraordinary to use the same payment gateway to do everything but i am probably asking for too much...

Waiting for answers, thanks in advance

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered out of scope on SO. You may, however, do a little looking around and come up with specific questions regarding tools that you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry but i dont get what you mean with your answer

Comment: You are asking SO's users to suggest a service that meets your needs. Our site's governance has decided that asking for suggestions is bad form, as they "tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" - [see point 4 at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is likely to be put on hold and to receive bad answers in its current state - if you revise it to ask about payment gateways you are interested in (or as a question asking for workarounds to the problem of needing pay for each merch acct), though, you will have much better luck!

Comment: If the question is wrongly asked then the moderators will take the necessary actions, you are not a moderator as far as i see so please, if you cant provide me with any help in regards to my question, feel free to leave the post, i appreciate your concern tho

Comment: [SO is a site moderated by its users just as much as the mods themselves](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Users with high enough rep actually have (almost) the same privileges as mods do. I was tasked with reviewing this question through the "First Question" review queue;  it is my duty to help you, as a new user, to understand the rules of the site so you can benefit from it as much as possible. I'm not trying to be a jerk or anything - promise!

Comment: As it stands I don't really know how to assist directly (my knowledge about this sort of software/service is practically nonexistent). Having asked similar questions in the past, though, I can offer some advice for a revision that would get more attention: look up a couple services that seem interesting to you, put together a list of criteria for the service you will eventually choose, and come to the community to see if the services you found can be made to conform to the chosen criteria. I've noted questions that have been phrased like this getting a lot more attention!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to be storing bank information and card data if you are not Level 1 PCI compliant.  There is a lot of financial liability if you do so.

There is a company called Base Commerce (www.basecommerce.com) which allows developers such as yourself to create a 'partner' account and associate multiple merchant accounts under it.  You can spin up or down as many accounts as you want, all programatically, at no cost (except for the small % transaction fees that are normal in payment processing).  You will also get commissions on the transactions your merchants process.